# Should we consider transitioning from AFNetworking to NSUrlSession?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, nsurlsession

I have been using `AFNetworking` for a while, however recently heard opinion `NSUrlSession` provides the same functionality as `AFNetworking`, so no need to use `AFNetworking`. Mostly I'm interested in these features like operations, clients and lazy image down-loader, however, not sure how much additional code I will need to write. Has anybody transitioned from `AFNetworking` to `NSUrlSession`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`NSURLSession` does not reproduce all of the richness of AFNetworking (notably, the construction of complex HTTP requests and the simplified parsing of the responses). So if you're leveraging these features of AFNetworking, then you might want to stay with AFNetworking.

For the programmer who is currently using `NSURLConnection`, though, `NSURLSession` offers some nice enhancements. The block-based methods of `NSURLSession` are richer than what was provided by `NSURLConnection`. Also, `NSURLSession` offers background session features that allow requests to continue even if the app isn't running.

For the AFNetworking developer using `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` (which is `NSURLConnection`-based), AFNetworking now offers `AFHTTPSessionManager`, a very similar interface that leverages `NSURLSession` internally (but, curiously, not `NSOperationQueue`-based). So, if you want to enjoy some `NSURLSession` features with AFNetworking, consider using `AFHTTPSessionManager` instead of `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`.

Answer (score 3):

AFNetworking is written on top of NSUrlSession hence no reason to go away from it unless you want to handle all of the implementation details which AFNetworking has already taken care of for you and more to the point it is tested by thousands of users on a daily basis hence is a pretty stable and mature library.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use it as I know the inner workings of the native NSUrlConnection and NSUrlSession, but for most people AFNetworking 2.X is much easier to work with. I wasn't a fan of AFNetworking 1.X which is why I got deeply into doing it myself before 2.X was available.